# Error al guardar datos en un array serializado

Tags: php, array

Estoy guardando datos de productos en un array, este es el modelo:

```
$producto = array(
  "mouse" => "23",
  "pc" => "34",
  "pendrive" => array(
    "kingtong" => "12",
    "sandix" => "6"
  ),
  "cables" => array(
    "pop" => array(
        "abc" => "7",
        "xyz" => "22"
    ),
    "nat" => array(
        "i-abc" => "9",
        "i-xyz" => "10"
    )
  )
);
```

Y así es como agrego un producto;

```
$nombre_modelo = "unidad";

$userid = 1;
$detalles = $app->traer($userid);
$serial = $detalles[0]['producto'];
$producto = unserialize($serial);

// echo '<pre>';
// var_dump($producto);
// echo '</pre>';

if(isset($_POST['add'])){
  array_push(
    $producto['cables'], array(
        $nombre_modelo => array(
            "hdmi" => $_POST['modelo1'],
            "vga" => $_POST['modelo1']
        )
    )
  );
}

print_r($producto['cables']);
// print_r($producto['cables'][1]['unidad']['hdmi']);

$nuevo_producto = serialize($producto);
$app->actualizar(3, $nuevo_producto);

?>

<br>
<br>
<form action="" method="post">
 <input type="number" name="modelo1" autocomplete="off" placeholder="modelo1"><br>
 <input type="number" name="modelo2" autocomplete="off" placeholder="modelo2"><br>
 <br>
 <input type="submit" name="add" value="Agregar">
</form>
```

Respuesta:

```
Array
(
[pop] => Array
    (
        [abc] => 7
        [xyz] => 22
    )

[nat] => Array
    (
        [i-abc] => 9
        [i-xyz] => 10
    )

[0] => Array
    (
        [stu] => Array
            (
                [modelo1] => 34
                [modelo2] => 14
            )
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [unidad] => Array
            (
                [hdmi] => 56
                [vga] => 56
            )
    )
)
```

El problema que tengo es que al agregar un producto al final de array, el indice figura con `0` y el titulo del producto figura después, cuando en debería figurar como los dos primero que estan arriba; `pop` y `nat`. No se si me estoy haciendo entender. Los ultimos dos objetos del array `0` y `1` deberían tener el nombre y productos.

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: intenta probar `'...'` despues de `$producto['cables']` de esta forma: `if(isset($_POST['add'])){array_push($producto['cables'], ...array($nombre_modelo => array( "hdmi" => $_POST['modelo1'], "vga" => $_POST['modelo1'])));}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que al usar [`array_push()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php) te colocará los elementos partiendo del último índice, o, si tal índice no existe empezará en el índice `0`.

Pero la estructura inicial de tu array indica que el nombre del modelo está como índice del sub-array, es decir, no usaste índices numéricos `0`, `1`, `2` ... desde el principio. Para seguir manteniendo esa estructura tendrías que cambiar esto:

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
  array_push(
    $producto['cables'], array(
        $nombre_modelo => array(
            "hdmi" => $_POST['modelo1'],
            "vga" => $_POST['modelo1']
        )
    )
  );
}
```

Por esto:

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
  $producto['cables'][$nombre_modelo] = array(
            "hdmi" => $_POST['modelo1'],
            "vga" => $_POST['modelo1']
  );
}
```

Eso hará que `$nombre_modelo` sustituya al índice secuencial que te produce `array_push` de forma automática.

Además, el Manual de PHP recomienda no usar `array_push()` para tu caso, porque sobrecargas el código llamando a una función, cuando lo puedes hacer prescindiendo de ella (esto es lo que dice en una nota, ver enlace al inicio de esta respuesta):

> **Nota**: Si se utiliza `array_push()` para añadir un solo elemento al array, es mejor utilizar `$array[] =` ya que de esta forma no existe
> la sobrecarga de llamar a una función.

Comment: Fui a la documentación, pero no leí la nota. Desde ya muchas gracias!